# Censored letters of the book Peri Haarets

Tags: history, jewish-books, chasidut-hasidism, censorship

I am looking for an uncensored version of the letters, from which we have a censored version in the standard versions of the Peri Haarets. I would appreciate some links.

Note. 
Peri Haarets is the book of Rav Menachem Mendel Mivitebsk, the main talmid of the Magid Mimezritsh, who migrated to Erets Israel with rabbi Avraham Mikalitsk, The book begins with drashot on Parahiot and the end is a compilation of letters from them from Erats Israel to their scholars who remained in Russia.I think that one of the reasons of the suppression of some letters is a controversy against the Baal Hatanya.

Comment: Could you clarify what this book is? Who wrote it?

Comment: Peri Haarets is the book of Rav Menachem Mendel Mivitebsk, the main talmid of the Magid Mimezritsh, who migrated to Erets Israel with rabbi Avraham Mikalitsk, The book begins with drashot on Parahiot and the end is a compilation of letters from them from Erats Israel to their schholars who remained in Russia.

Comment: What parts are missing that someone would know if they came upon the uncensored version?

Comment: In my edition they say that some letters wasn't included on the edition because of the advice of Rabanim

Comment: https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=21741#p=14&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=    maybe this is a source

Answer (score 2):

I have found a great amount of letters in [Igrot Chasidim Meerets Israel](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=21741#p=14&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=). From 10 to 78, almost all letters are by RMMV and RAK.From the Igeret 20, we see that RMMV makes some allusions that the Chasidim need to behave simply and with humility, and not to try to intellectualize th Avoda, to deal with a great amount of concepts derived from Chochmat Hakabala, and that he try to maintain his leadership despite he is far from the Chasidim. There is perhaps a masked conflict with RSZ about the mastery. After RMM deceased, the conflict has been stronger, with financial consequences.

Most of the letters not included are about a controversy between RA Kalitsker and RSZ Miladi. They don't contain divre Tora.

Comment: Which letters in this source are you referring to?

Comment: From letter 11, up to 78, but in the middle there are a few letters from others Rabanim